# Redux mapDispatchToProps access action within array.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to get an action to be available within a function that is called within array.map. Passing the props from parent component to subcomponent is happening. It feels like it should be a simple task to make it available within the array.map function, but that has not proven successful.

Here's an updated example code:

In this example, being able to properly pass the 'actionUpdate' function to listItem is what I have not accomplished successfully.

```
function listItem(item,index) {
    const id = item.id

    const handleUpdated = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        actionUpdate(id);
    };
    return (
        <Button
            onClick={handleUpdated}
            color='primary'
            variant='contained'
            style={{ marginTop: '0.75rem' }}
        >
            Update
        </Button>

    );
}
function MyList(props) {
    const { streams } = props;

    return (
        <List>
            {streams.map(listItem)};
        </List>
    );
}

function listView(props) {
    const { classes, streams } = props;

    return (
        <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
            <section className={classes.content}>
                <Grid container>
                    <Grid item style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                        <MyList
                            streams={streams}
                            actionUpdate={actionUpdate}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </section>
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const streams = R.path(['theObject', 'arrayOfObjects'])
    )(state);
    return { streams };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    const actionUpdate = (itemId) => {
        return dispatch(theUpdateAction(itemId));
    };
    return { actionUpdate };
};

const MainListView = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(listView);

export default withStyles(styles)(MainListView);
```

I have my state and actions mapped to props using connect, mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps.

What I need to achieve is having access to the action from the dispatch within the listItem function.

Comment: Its kind of difficult to see what you're doing without a minimal reproducible example.. I would say try to access `listItem` by doing `props.listItem`

Comment: @MattOestreich I added a more complete example

Comment: Can you use something like CodeSandbox or StackBlitz to create a reproducible example? It is extremely difficult to see what you are trying to do. Help me help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define listItem within MyList, which would provide it access to MyList's props including updateAction.

```
function MyList(props) {
    const { streams, actionUpdate } = props;

    // Can access updateAction here
    const listItem = (item,index) => {
        const id = item.id

        const handleUpdated = e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            actionUpdate(id);
        };
        return (
            <Button
                onClick={handleUpdated}
                color='primary'
                variant='contained'
               style={{ marginTop: '0.75rem' }}
            >
                Update
            </Button>
        );
       }

    return (
        <List>
            {streams.map(listItem)};
        </List>
    );
}

function listView(props) {
    const { classes, streams } = props;

    return (
        <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
            <section className={classes.content}>
                <Grid container>
                    <Grid item style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                        <MyList
                            streams={streams}
                            actionUpdate={actionUpdate}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </section>
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const streams = R.path(['theObject', 'arrayOfObjects'])
    )(state);
    return { streams };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    const actionUpdate = (itemId) => {
        return dispatch(theUpdateAction(itemId));
    };
    return { actionUpdate };
};

const MainListView = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(listView);

export default withStyles(styles)(MainListView);
```

Comment: this is by far the most straight forward answer and works. Thank you. I was hoping to keep them separate because it makes for a very large MyList component, but working is best.